# Mongoid query with where clause on an association of an embeded document

Tags: mongoid

I have a Rails app using Mongoid with the classes `User`, `ContractAgreement` and `ContractVersions`.

The relationships are the following: `User` embeds `ContractAgreement`, and `ContractAgreement` belong to `ContractVersions`, like so:

**User**:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Stateful
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  [...]
  embeds_many :contract_agreements
```

**ContractAgreement**:

```
class ContractAgreement
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :user
  belongs_to :contract_version
  field :date_of_agreement, type: DateTime
```

**ContractVersion**

```
class ContractVersion
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :version, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :status, type: String
  has_one :post, autosave: true

  has_one :post, autosave: true
  #has_many :contract_agreements
```

As you can see, `#has_many :contract_agreements` is commented out as Mongoid didn't like the association to an embeded document.

Is there a way of getting the list of Users that have agreed to a specified contract?

I've tried both doing `$elemMatch` all the way:

```
[64] pry(main)> reload!; 
     u = User.all.select{|u| u.contract_agreements.count > 0}.first ; 
     cv = u.contract_agreements.first.contract_version ; 
     User.where(contract_agreements: {'$elemMatch' => {contract_version: {'$elemMatch' => {_id: cv._id}}}}).count
Reloading...
=> 0
```

As well as the compressed single query notation:

```
[64] pry(main)> reload!; 
     u = User.all.select{|u| u.contract_agreements.count > 0}.first ;
     cv = u.contract_agreements.first.contract_version ; 
     User.where("contract_agreements.contract_version._id"  => cv._id).count
Reloading...
=> 0
```

I know the contract version id I am asking for exists since I explicitly select a user that has one.

Is such a query even possible or do I need to de-embed ContractAgreement?   If it is possible, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the foreign key worked:

```
[73] pry(main)> reload!; 
     u = User.all.select{|u| u.contract_agreements.count > 0}.first ; 
     cv = u.contract_agreements.first.contract_version ;
     User.where("contract_agreements.contract_version_id"  => cv._id).count
Reloading...
=> 1
```